# How can I recognize the indefinite articles "a" or "an"?

Tags: java, regex

My task is to devise a regular expression that will recognize the indefinite article in English – the word “a” or “an” i.e. to write a regular expression to identify the word a or the word an. I must test the expression by writing a test driver which reads a file containing approximately ten lines of text. Your program should count the occurrences of the words “a” and “an”. I shall not match the characters a and an in words such as th**an**.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexeFindText {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      // Input for matching the regexe pattern
       String file_name = "Testing.txt";
   
           ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
           String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();  
           String asString = Arrays.toString(aryLines);
       
            // Regexe to be matched
               String regexe = ""; //<<--this is where the problem lies
       
           int i;
           for ( i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++ ) {
           System.out.println( aryLines[ i ] ) ;
           }
   

      // Step 1: Allocate a Pattern object to compile a regexe
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexe);
      //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexe, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);  
      // case-        insensitive matching

      // Step 2: Allocate a Matcher object from the compiled regexe pattern,
      //         and provide the input to the Matcher
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(asString);

      // Step 3: Perform the matching and process the matching result

      // Use method find()
      while (matcher.find()) {     // find the next match
         System.out.println("find() found the pattern \"" + matcher.group()
               + "\" starting at index " + matcher.start()
               + " and ending at index " + matcher.end());
      }

      // Use method matches()
      if (matcher.matches()) {
         System.out.println("matches() found the pattern \"" + matcher.group()
               + "\" starting at index " + matcher.start()
               + " and ending at index " + matcher.end());
      } else {
         System.out.println("matches() found nothing");
      }

      // Use method lookingAt()
      if (matcher.lookingAt()) {
         System.out.println("lookingAt() found the pattern \"" + matcher.group()
               + "\" starting at index " + matcher.start()
               + " and ending at index " + matcher.end());
      } else {
         System.out.println("lookingAt() found nothing");
      }
   }
}
```

What do I have to use to find those words within my text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the regex that will match "a" or "an":

```
String regex = "\\ban?\\b";
```

Let's break that regex down:

- `\b` means word boundary (a single back slash is written as `"\\"` in java)
- `a` is simply a literal `"a"`
- `n?` means zero or one literal `"n"`

Comment: I would have rather seen for a homework tag some leading questions to help him, or at least more of an explanation of *why* that's the answer.

Comment: @Mikeb Explanation has been added. (I'm a bit of a rep whore, so I like to post the basic answer first to be first, then tidy it up and embellish it with a following edit)

Comment: If anyone is looking up how to do "or" in regex, without backreferencing it, its (:?a|an) rather than (a|an), see http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: @cloth no, it isn't. That's a non-capturing group, which is irrelevant to a regex "or". And by the way, you have a syntax error: it's `(?:regex)`, not `(:?regex)`